# Random frame offset on particles

Tags: particles

Trying to create a stadium crowd via particles and 2D planes. The particles are randomly generated by and locked along a reference geometry representing the bleachers/stands.

Now how do I randomize the start frame of the image sequences that are projected onto those planes?

Rendering as collection of a dozen image planes with different fans. Need the start frames as randomized as possible for effect.

[image]

Comment: It's not easy to interpret your terse question.  Do you mean that you are rendering "Render As" "Collection" with "image as plane" objects?  And that these planes are movie clips that you want to set the Offset to the frame when the particle is created?  (Don't respond to this with a comment: edit your question above to add some detail; you'll get help faster)

Comment: Tried again. Thanks!

Comment: Also, how do I address the render issue with transparencies as visible in the example image? The darker fans apparently randomly receiving shadowing from transparent/masked part of image planes as you can tell by the hard edges cutting off along the image plane geo edges.